# how do i concatenate two files in rust?

Tags: rust

I have `txt1.txt` and `txt2.txt`, how do i concatenate these files into `txt1.txt` using rust?

```
use std::fs;
use std::io;
use std::io::{Read, Write};

fn main() {
    let mut txt1 = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .write(true)
        .open("txt1.txt")
        .unwrap();
    
    let mut txt2 = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .write(true)
        .open("txt2.txt")
        .unwrap();
    
    let result = io::copy(&mut txt2.txt, &mut txt1.txt).unwrap();
    println!("final txt size = {}", result);
}
```

Comment: Open the file and write the contents of the first file and then the contents of the second file?

Comment: I see you already wrote some code. Is there a particular problem with this code?

Comment: It seems to be overwriting the contents of txt1

Comment: You say you wanna concatenate into `txt1.txt`, yet you open that file as read-only?

Comment: oh that line got deleted but i did add write
.edit, i fixed it
. still broken

Answer (score 2):

the below code will work for your question

```
use std::{fs, io};


fn main() {
    
    let mut txt1 = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .open("./txt1.txt")
        .unwrap();
    
    let mut txt2 = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open("./txt2.txt")
        .unwrap();

    let result = io::copy(&mut txt2, &mut txt1);
    println!("Result: {:?}", result);
}
```

if you want get rid off `unwrap()` functions following code is your answer

```
use std::{fs, io};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()>{
    
    let mut txt1 = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .append(true)
        .open("./txt1.txt")?;
    
    let mut txt2 = fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .open("./txt2.txt")?;

    let result = io::copy(&mut txt2, &mut txt1)?;
    println!("Result Len: {}", result);

    Ok(())
}
```